# Object falling from scene

Tags: physics

im new to the blender and i have some problem with the imported 3D model.

I want to make a 3D animation of this 3D bottle rotating and the liquid inside would move.

PROBLEM is that when i hit play - one of the layers(condensation on the bottle) will fall from the scene.

Can anyone guide me how to make that condensation stay on the bottle and maybe even trip/move as the bottle rotates, as well the liquid inside?

Images of the "condensation falling"
[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you "Convert" the condensation particles to mesh?  If so you could 'parent' the lot to the bottle.

Comment: Hey, @Edgel3D thank you for the suggestion. I tried that and when i hit play, the bottle will start to move to the left for some reason and the condensation+ liquid will stay in one spot.

Comment: Ha ha, well at least they're not falling to the ground.  If the bottle moves, the converted particles if parented, should follow it.  When things start moving or distorting on their own it usually means there's a modifier working on one or both objects. If it's possible to "Apply" modifiers, that can help.  Or one modifier might have to be higher in the modifier list than another.   Straight out mesh shouldn't move unless keyframed to do so or physics & Forces are at play.  Have you tried using the bottle's and/or particle's 'stickiness' settings ?

Comment: Another thought, I see you're rotating the bottle, so it could just be the bottle's Origin point.  Select the bottle at frame 1, press T and at left choose "Origin Point".  Click on Origin to Geometry.  The arrows should move to roughly the center.  Try rotating it manually, see if it stays at the one spot before trying the animation again.